# Finding a few different matches using regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to check for

1. `'@username'`
2. `'@username,'`
3. `'@username '`
4. `'@username.'`
5. `'@username. '`
6. `'@username:'`
7. `'@username: '`

I currently have this:

```
$post->message = preg_replace(
    '/@ *('.preg_quote($speak['username'], '/').') *:/i',
    '[url=\''.PAGE_URL.RELATIVE_WBB_DIR.'/index.php?page=User&userID='.$speak['toID'].'\']@'.$speak['username'].':[/url]',
    $post->message);
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can modify this to accept those inputs?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your regex to add in the punctuation:

```
$post->message = preg_replace(
    '/@ *('.preg_quote($speak['username'], '/').')[:,.]? */i',
    '[url=\''.PAGE_URL.RELATIVE_WBB_DIR.'/index.php?page=User&userID='.$speak['toID'].'\']@'.$speak['username'].':[/url]',
    $post->message);
```

Note the added part:

```
/@ *('.preg_quote($speak['username'], '/').')[:,.]? */i
                                             ^^^^^^
```

Which optionally matches one of those characters (colon, comma, period).

Comment: You already had it in your original regex, with ` *` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression that should achieve what you are looking for:

```
/^@[a-zA-Z]+[:\.\,]?[ ]?$/

/^@         // string starts with '@'
[a-zA-Z]+   // contains any letter at least once
[:\.\,]?    // may contain any : , . zero or one time
[ ]?$       // may contain a whitespace zero or one time at end of string
```